# Is $\frac{ax}{z}+\frac{by}{z}=c$ a linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was thinking about the equation $ax+by+d=cz$ here, $a, b, c, d \in R$. But here I set $d=0$ so the equation is $ax+by=cz$ here $x, y, z$ are variables. This equation is a linear equation, right?

When I want to throw $z$ to other side, the equation becomes $\frac{ax}{z}+\frac{by}{z}=c$. Is this equation linear and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, an equation of variables $x_1, ..., x_n$ is linear if it can be written in the form $a_0 + a_1 x_1 + ... + a_n x_n = 0$, where $a_01, ..., a_n$ are coefficients in your field (here, $\mathbb{R}$). So yes, your equation is linear, even without setting d = 0. :)

$\frac{ax}{z} + \frac{by}{z} = c$ simply is another way to write it, so you can still say it's a linear equation, even though its expression isn't. But we usually don't risk writing it that way (what if $z$ was $0$?)